# Smart Capture - embed on external website - CORS issue

Tags: marketing-cloud, smart-capture

I am facing the below error message, when I am trying to submit the Smart capture form embedded on a Webpage.

Strangely the data is correctly passed and saved to the list in SFMC.
But only the page does NOT get redirected!

> Uncaught DOMException: Permission denied to access property "assign" on cross-origin object smartcapture-formjs.js:516
> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://e.s11.exct.net/v1. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).

Can anyone help me to understand and resolve this issue.

[image]

Comment: Disable Same Origin Policy on the Webserver / Page that you have implemented the form into? It is not really recommended because of security reasons.

Comment: @JohannesSchapdick thanks for the work around. Sure I will check with the team if we can disable ONLY for the page and will let you know if it worked.

Comment: @VishalKumarCV how did you handle this? I have the similar issue like yours.